# SetCursorPos in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I code with visual c++, and i use wxwidget 3.x., Windows 10

I would like to use SetCursorPos (to move my camera, and let the mouse cursor stay in middle of screen), but i got some error message:

```
canvas.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetCursorPos@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CanvasFrame::setCursorPos(int,int)" (?setCursorPos@CanvasFrame@@QAEXHH@Z)
```

I m not sure i can use SetCursorPos via wwxwidget, i think wxwidget manage this, but cant find it on google …

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

My bad …
this->WarpPointer(renderer->GetWidth() / 2, renderer->GetHeight() / 2);
works..

Thanks anyway :)